# Retrieve DNS Flags information (in Hexadecimal format)

Tags: python, scapy

I have used scapy to retrieve DNS information as much as I could, but I would like to know what to do in order to get the DNS flag information.

The below are the information that I retrieve from Scapy but I not sure how to convert it to Hexa decimal format because I am not too familiar with DNS flag.

```
    id        = 1
    qr        = 0L
    opcode    = QUERY
    aa        = 0L
    tc        = 0L
    rd        = 0L
    ra        = 0L
    z         = 0L
    rcode     = ok
    qdcount   = 1
    ancount   = 0
    nscount   = 0
    arcount   = 0
```

Comment: Why do you need it in hexadecimal format? Most of the flags you've listed are binary, just 1 or 0.

Comment: because one of the program that I am using requires hexadecimal for DNS flags. But what I can get from scapy are binaries.

Comment: You need individual flags as hexadecimal or the flag field as a whole in hexadecimal?

Comment: As a whole, like how we see it in wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [DNS protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197470%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), the flags are bit-packed into a 16-bit value, like this:

```
| 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |  9 |  8 |  7 |  6 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |  0 |
| qr | opcode            | aa | tc | rd | ra | z            | rcode             |
```

See [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/amislove/teaching/cs4700/fall09/handouts/project1-primer.pdf) for a bit more information.

You can construct this value in Python like this:

```
flags = (qr << 15) | (opcode << 11) | (aa << 10) | (tc << 9) | (rd << 8) | (ra << 7) | (z << 4) | rcode
```

If you want to output the hexadecimal representation of this value, you can use the [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) or [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) functions.

Comment: But for opcode and rcode, they return a string. opcode = QUERY and rcode = ok, will it still works?

Comment: @JamesYeo No, it won't work if those are strings.  You need to get the integer values those strings represent (e.g. QUERY = 0).

Comment: Thanks will go try it out

Comment: By the way, I think if `pkt` is your packet object then `pkt[DNS].opcode` will contain the numeric value of the opcode.

Comment: Yup seems to be able to work. The result I got is 0x80L, this means it works right? cause I not sure the exact hexadecimal that should be correct (I am totally clueless about DNS flags)

Comment: Thank You very much for your help :)

Comment: yea I have made the changes already. Just curious, why is my flag request value is 128 and my response value is 16576? any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86957/discussion-between-augurar-and-james-yeo).

Comment: I understand that 256 and flag above 32700++ is required for normal request and response.
but your method, it gave me the value of 128 and 16576
not sure whether which part of the code went wrong

Answer (score 1):

DNS flags correspond to bytes 3rd and 4th bytes. You can get those using:
`bytes(packet[DNS])[2:4] # Use str if you are on scapy version < 3`

If you use it to input into graphic tool by hand, you can easily see the value by printing the bytes. Or you can use struct.unpack to convert it to integer, which you can convert to hex using hex.

Comment: Can you be more specific? packet[DNS] worked? str(packet[DNS]) worked? What did you get?

Comment: I tired str(bytes(pkt[DNS])[2:4]) and str(pkt[DNS])[2:4] and (pkt[DNS])[2:4], it does not print out anything. Is this the correct format that you mention?

Comment: Use print to see the value of the expression

Comment: I tried to print pkt[DNS] and it gives me some weird characters and the url of the website that i pinged

Comment: And what does print str(pkt[DNS])[2:4] give you? You can run it through scapy's hexstr if you wish, too.

Comment: it gives me a blank output.